# Firebase Cross-project function „listening“ for firestore actions in different project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I got two projects in Firebase, let‘s say A and B. To keep things simple let‘s say project A just uses Firebase cloud functions and project B is using firestore.

I‘ve already learned that I have to create a custom Service Account to grant the cloud function access to another project‘s database (firestore).

Now I would like to know **if/how** I can use a cloud function in project A utilizing a background trigger (e.g.: document.onCreate) which is „listening“ to the firestore of project B and fires when something is being changed in the project B‘s database?
I couldn‘t find any restrictions mentioned in the docs, which state it‘s not possible but I don‘t quite know how to go about this.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. Firestore triggers work through Cloud PubSub and are tied to the original project.

Your workaround would be to write a Firestore triggered background function that then *forwards* the message from the source project to the destination project so that it can be processed in that target project.

This would incur double charges because you would be running two Cloud Functions for every change.

Another workaround would be to run the function in the first project in the context of a service account from the second project, or with a service account from the first project that has permissions in the second project. This kind of cross-project access is easy to set up and is the same as the permissions you’d need to access Firestore as described in your last question.

There are limitations on all of these approaches that are rather extensive. I’d encourage you to elaborate on why you need a particular configuration to ensure that you’re not describing an XY problem.

The short answer is that you cannot do what you’ve described but you can achieve similar results through a variety of workarounds.

Comment: Okay, that‘s unfortunate! I guess in this case I will try to solve my problem by using a pubsub schedule instead, but thank you for your answers!